# Find all combinations of palindromic substrings

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations

How to find all possible combinations of palindromic substrings for some randomly entered string in Python? For example, if entered **xxyx** what should be returned is :

```
[['xx', 'y', 'x'], ['x', 'xyx'], ['x', 'x', 'y', 'x']] .
```

I know how to get all substrings and check if it is palindrome,but can`t find a way to combine into correct solution as shown. I am sorry if question isnt asked correctly, it's my first.

Here is the code:

```
def find_all_subsets(seq, n):

    if n == 0:
        return [[]]

    else:
        result = []
        subsets = find_all_subsets(seq, n-1)

        for subset in subsets:
            result += [subset]

            result += [[seq[n-1]] + subset]

        return result


def check_palindrome(subsetsList):
    finalList = []
    for set in subsetsList:
        if set[::-1] == set:
            finalList.append(set)
        else:
           continue

    return finalList



if __name__ == "__main__":
    word = "xxyx"
    palindromicSubsets = check_palindrome(find_all_subsets(word, len(word)))
    print(palindromicSubsets)
```

Comment: Not a bad first question, BUT! You should add the code you have already tried. At the moment it is too broad, but if you have already done the work and just neglected to show it, I think correcting that oversight will leave it in a good state. (Oh, and please edit your question to do so. Long code snippets format _terribly_ in the comments.)

Comment: Well,everything i have tried so far was only giving me all possible palindromic substrings within that string, i wasn't even close to combine them like i should.I can show that code,but i am not sure it will make question less broad.

Comment: Can you explain why in your expected output the list is broken up like that? I would expect the _set_ of palindromic substrings to be, well, a set, or maybe a list, but it seems arbitrary why those are in nested lists.

Comment: Well,it only matter to get all possible ways to divide the input string into palindromic substrings,like Blckknght corrected. Way on which that should/must be implemented was not specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to be looking not for all palindromic substrings, but rather for all the ways you can divide the input string up into palindromic substrings. (There's always at least one way, since one-character substrings are always palindromes.)

Here's the way I've done it:

```
def palindromic_substrings(s):
    if not s:
        return [[]]
    results = []
    for i in range(len(s), 0, -1):
        sub = s[:i]
        if sub == sub[::-1]:
            for rest in palindromic_substrings(s[i:]):
                results.append([sub] + rest)
    return results
```

There's two loops. The outer loop checks each length of initial substring (in descending length order) to see if it is a palindrome. If so, it recurses on the rest of the string and loops over the returned values, adding the initial substring to each item before adding it to the results.

A slightly more Pythonic approach would be to make a recursive generator:

```
def palindromic_substrings(s):
    if not s:
        yield []
        return
    for i in range(len(s), 0, -1):
        sub = s[:i]
        if sub == sub[::-1]:
            for rest in palindromic_substrings(s[i:]):
                yield [sub] + rest
```

Comment: Thank you for solution and as well for nice explanation !